# Can I select music from my iPhone/iPad and it plays on my Samsung Smart TV

Tags: itunes, television

The title says it all, but to give a little more detail.

What I want to be able to do is to sit on my sofa, and select music via my iPhone or iPad and then that music is played on my TV (which is connected to my Hi-Fi).

Is this possible? I really want to use the native music selection from the phone.

I don't really want to buy AppleTV, as I already have enough computers in the house in theory to make this kind of system possible.

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: If the TV is already connected to the Hi-Fi, then is there a problem connecting the device to the Hi-Fi as a source via the headphone jack?. Or is your question really you want to stream from the device directly to the TV.

Comment: I really want the iPhone/iPad to act as the remote control. I don't really mind where the music comes from (a server, the phone itself). I mainly dislike picking music with the TV remote, it's so clunky.

Comment: If you have a Mac with the same library, you can use the device as a remote for that. So does it matter if the sound comes out of the TV! or are you really wanting it to come out of the Hi-Fi but control it with the device.Can you be more specific. Doing so will help get you an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. I use [ArkMC](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/arkmc-dlna-upnp-media-streaming/id405487397?mt=8) to stream all my music to Samsung Smart TV. I even can browse artists, playlists, albums from Samsung TV.  For me,  it's more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have first hand experience with this, but http://www.imediashare.tv/ looks like it could possibly work. Looks like it connects to DLNA capable TVs. In any case you're going to need to use 3rd party applications on the iphone to connect to the TV.

If you want to use Apple's Airplay, you can either buy an AppleTV (Which you've said you don't want to do), use a PC to connect to your sound system and install XBMC or other software capable of Airplay connectivity, or buy an Airport Express.